# What does "strip Swift symbols" in Xcode actually do?

Tags: ios, xcode, strip, app-thinning

When exporting an archive of a project containing Swift, we get the option to "strip Swift symbols". I haven't seen any difference in app size though in a project with just one dummy Swift file, thus a perfect case for maximum stripping.

What does this do exactly and how does it affect the final app size (.ipa)?

[image]

P.S: as seen in Xcode 9 beta 6

UPDATE: actually I can observe a slight ipa size reduction (3.4 MB uncompressed) when looking at specific devices variants (not for universal variant though)

Comment: The only thing I can think of in this context is **reverse engineering**. But to make you sure, you still will be able to see readable crashes. I can confirm that builds still include debug symbols *(dSYM)* with *Strip Swift symbols* flag `enabled`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [Xcode docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html):

> The new Strip Swift Symbols (`STRIP_SWIFT_SYMBOLS`) build setting is
>   enabled by default. It adjusts the level of symbol stripping so that
>   when the linked product of the build is stripped, all Swift symbols
>   are removed. This significantly reduces the size of Swift frameworks.
>   If the lack of Swift symbols causes problems, such as when using
>   `dladdr()`, this setting can be disabled. To view the exported symbols
>   from file that has been stripped, use `xcrun dyldinfo -export` instead
>   of `nm`. (31306055)

Comment: `nm -g -U` on a binary produces a similar result to `xcrun dyldinfo -export`

Comment: This flag is silently removed: No longer available in Xcode 13.4, no update in the release notes

Comment: as of Xcode 14 `xcrun dyld_info -exports`